# Make iPad Pro Screen Bigger with External Monitor?

Tags: ipad, display

If I display my iPad on an external monitor, does it just mirror the iPad screen, or can I actually get more content? I have a work iPad that I would like to use as a desktop, with the goal of displaying significantly more information than I can display on the 10" screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than specific apps that support multi-screen mode, the iPad will be exactly mirrored. The iPad doesn't care if it's a 7-inch or 70-inch screen, and it will only mirror. The apps that support an external display are few and far between, and there are probably only a single-digit number of them. I'm sorry if your goal was to get more space on an external monitor using an iPad, but it won't happen natively (I guess it could happen with jailbreaking?).

Comment: Thanks. Are there list of apps that support multi-screen mode?

Comment: I couldn’t find any list of them, but while searching I found that this app https://www.shiftscreen.app allows iPad to use split screen with over 250 apps.